# md-autocomplete finds data, but dropdown is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

`md-autocomplete` with `findUser` method finds data, but dropdown is absolutely empty

How to fix mentioned empty dropdown (even no dropdown) issue?

Thank you!

```
angular.module('orders', ['ngMaterial']);

angular.module('orders').config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('green')
        .accentPalette('grey');
});

angular.module('orders').controller('order', function ($scope, $http) {
    var self = this;
    self.data = null;
    self.selectedItem = null;
    self.searchText = null;

    this.findUser = function (query) {
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl() + 'user',
            data: query
        }).then(function (data) { return self.data = data; });
    };//...
```

Here is my full html page, check it, please

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="1.5.0/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script src="1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="1.1.1/angular-material.min.css" />
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
    <script src="order/order.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='orders' layout="column" ng-controller="order as ctrl">
    <div flex="85">
        <md-autocomplete flex="85" md-selected-item="ctrl.selectedItem" md-search-text="ctrl.searchText"
        md-items="item in ctrl.findUser(ctrl.searchText)" md-item-text="ctrl.formatUser(item)" md-delay="300"
        md-floating-label="Search supplier representative">
            <div layout="row" class="item" layout-align="start center">
                <span md-highlight-text="ctrl.searchText">{{item.lastName}}</span>
            </div>
        </md-autocomplete>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `findUser` function is returning incorrect data, instead use:

```
this.findUser = function (query) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: apiUrl() + 'user',
        data: query
    ̶}̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶ ̶{̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶s̶e̶l̶f̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶ ̶}̶)̶;̶
    }).then(function (response) { return self.data = response.data; });
};//...
```

The `$http.then` method returns a `response` object of which `data` is a property.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Call the findUser() method on ‘ngModelChange’ event in md-autocomplete. 
Create a new variable, let’s say self.users=[]
And assign the data from server to this array, then on the html, iterate this array.